# Accessing attributes from another model but same controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, stripe-payments

I have an events controller with a `payment` method that calls `save_with_payment` method from the registration model, the method in the registration model needs to get the `price` of the event to build the payment & registration but how do I access the price attribute?

Thanks :)

Comment: Any chance you could share what you've already tried? With some examples ideally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose it with `attr_accessible` and then you can access it with `@event.price`

Comment: Will this work with mongoid? I am not using activerecord. Apologies, I forgot to tag the question with Mongodb.